# Fired OnClick event in a LinearLayout is restricted to a very small zone

Tags: android, onclick

I want to use some LinearLayouts on my app to make a certain action if the user clicks on them outside of elements they may have with "active" behaviors like EditTexts, Buttons or similar things.

In one of these LinearLayouts I've set a pair of EditText and with them being shown the OnClick event only is detected in a small area of the layout, even if the click happens far from those EditTexts. Maybe that clicks are doing a focus on one of my EditText when they are performed, but ironically the event fires in an area which is more near to the EditTexts than other ones where the click is ignored.

I've also checked that this doesn't happen with some other elements, if I press even not only near, but over a TextView or ImageView the event is fired properly.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

PS: Per request I'm giving the code of how the linearlayout is used, though I did it programmaticaly not by xml:

```
    protected EditText initInput(EditText selectedInput) 
    {

    selectedInput = new EditText(this);

    selectedInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    return selectedInput;

   }

   ...

    AlertDialog dialog = null;
    EditText input;

    EditText input2;


    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

      dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(ll)
                .create();

     dialog.setCancelable(true);

     TextView tv = new TextView(this);

     ll.addView(tv,layoutParams);

     input = initInput(input);

     ll.addView(input,layoutParams);

     TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);

     ll.addView(tv2,layoutParams);  

     input2 = initInput(input2);

     ll.addView(input2,layoutParams);
```

Comment: Post your xml please

Comment: Done, though I didn't use XML.

Comment: Where's the code for `initInput`?

Comment: @JoãoMagalhães, I put the initInput code, anyway I think it has nothing to do with the error.